# Adjust scrolling after font increase/decrease

Tags: scrolling, editing

After `text-scale-decrease` or `text-scale-increase` scrolling (e.g. with space, `scroll-down`) does not seem to take the text scaling into account. Is there a way to adjust the `scroll` commands to reflect these sorts of changes in text size?

Comment: The question is not clear. Please provide a step-by-step recipe (starting from `emacs -Q`), saying what you expect (want to see) at each step and what you see instead.

Comment: You'll have to describe what you mean by "text scaling into account". Perhaps the solution is not related to scrolling.